# Scroll down to hide navbar not working on mobile

Tags: scroll, navbar

I am using this script to function my navbar scroll down to hide, scroll up to show. My script is here.

```
<scrip>
var menu = document.getElementById("navbar");

document.addEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);

function handleScrollUp() {
  console.log("UP");
  menu.style.bottom = "0";
}

function handleScrollDown() {
  console.log("DOWN");
  menu.style.bottom = "-60px";
}

function handleScroll(event) {
  if ((event.wheelDelta && event.wheelDelta > 0) || event.deltaY < 0) {
    handleScrollUp();
  } else {
    handleScrollDown();
  }
}
</script>
```

(my navbar is at the bottom of the site)

It works well on Safari, Chrome, but not on any mobile device. Anybody knows what's the reason? I rly just need it to also work on mobile. Thanks!!!